# Center Bootstrap Contact Form

Tags: forms, css, bootstrap-4

I'm setting up a contact form and I want this form to be centered on my page. But I don't want the full width (col-md-12) of the page. I only want the width of a col-md-6 at the center of the page. Problem is that because I select col-md-6, the form display on the left hand side of the page. How can I center it?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
            <form action="contact" method="post"> {{--action = where the data must go--}}

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mobile">Mobile Nr:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Nr should start with 08, 07 or 06">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Your message...</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. Could you share your css please?
I am thinking about adding a margin:auto to the col-md to center it inside it's parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I see is adding two more divisions with col-md-3 on either side of your form div like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form action="contact" method="post"> {{--action = where the data must go--}}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile Nr:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Nr should start with 08, 07 or 06">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Your message...</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="cold-md-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what the Dr ordered. Thx!

Comment: Glad I could help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "m-auto" class in your col-md-6 div. Like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
        <form action="contact" method="post"> {{--action = where the data must go--}}

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input t`enter code here`ype="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile Nr:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Nr should start with 08, 07 or 06">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Your message...</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```